# CSS Class not formatable while ID works

Tags: html, css

I am learning HTML and CSS and I found one weird thing, despite training that I watch, and copy this step by step(using Visual Studio Code) I am unable to apply any style to any part of HTML file, when I add a Class to it. However, if I add ID, style applies.

My setting:

Visual Studio Code
Separate CSS and HTML File.

Example of  not working code:

```
<div Class="Author">

        <h1> About the Author</h1>
        <img src="image link here">
    </div>
```

however, if I change above code to this:

```
<div ID="Author">

        <h1> About the Author</h1>
        <img src="image link here">
    </div>
```

This does work.

Yes, I do change properly the CSS file to be either "." or "#" is there anything I miss here?

Comment: You are missing here to show us   those CSS  styles you are talking about... Create [mre] using snippet by pressing a button `<>` in editor.

Comment: Show us the css. 
Also note that you are using capitalized `Class` (instad of `class`) and uppercase `ID`(instad of `id`)

Comment: Please show us your CSS, as it could be a typo. To answers pointing out the capitalization of `Class` and `ID` - it doesn't matter and is only a stylistic choice. `.` and `#` would still be applied to any capitalization choice. Also, before posting an answer, wait until OP posts a minimal example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this works:

```
<div Class="Author">
```

it should be lowercase:

```
<div class="Author">
```

and then in the css reference it like

```
.Author {color: red}
```

Comment: As you can see in answer  with snippet below this one, it works.

Comment: #Author will override the directions in .Author if they are both in the same css file

Comment: OK, i know that, and that is relevant how? Nether do you see that is the question, and user stated `I do change properly` so it is insinuating that it changes and not have booth, and you did not mention that in answer... And you shouldn't, because, there is no reason for it...

Comment: try making the className class="Author" .Author{} to be class="author" .author{} - I never use capitals to begin a class name

Comment: Thanks for all replies...for some reason in my Visual Studio Code, when I used Uppercase for Class and ID it didn't work, I have no idea why, I tried to delete and recreate that few times just to find out if I had some typo there, but effect was the same all the time - Didn't work. After changing to lowercase id and class, also the names of them this started to work 0.o  So it looks like this now <div class="author"> and .author {color:red;}

Answer (score 0):

This functions correctly. You didn't give us css to work from so this is the best I can offer.

```css
#Author {
  color: red;
}

.Author {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<!-- no css applied -->
<div ID="no_css">
  <h1> About the Author</h1>
  <img src="image link here">
</div>

<!-- css applied to `ID` using `#` -->
<div ID="Author">
  <h1> About the Author</h1>
  <img src="image link here">
</div>

<!-- css applied to `Class` using `.` -->
<div Class="Author">
  <h1> About the Author</h1>
  <img src="image link here">
</div>
```

Comment: So you resorted to guessing. Op clearly stated he knows how to target class and id. So problem must be somewhere else.

Comment: @ikiK Yet my answer answers OPs question.

Comment: No it does not, question is:`is there something I miss heRE?` And you can not answer that without seeing reproducible example of problem. he is obliviously using `.`.. and `.#`. witch your answer is suggesting.

Comment: @ikiK It does as the issue was in the use of `.` or `#`. I simply used my own css.

Comment: `Yes, I do change properly the CSS file to be either "." or "#" `